# Understanding the condition of collinearity of three points

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

The following is a section from *Educative Commentary on JEE 2008 - Mathematics - by K.D.Joshi*, which is an optional internet resource* for students preparing for the JEE (India). The following image is a solution for a problem which needs collinearity of three points to be satisfied:

[image]

I do not have any trouble in understanding Statement-(2) which directly follows from the fact that "*If three points are collinear then the area formed by the points will be zero*".

It would be great if you could explain what is the meaning of Statement-(1) in the above image? How can the same rule be applied to $n$-dimensional space (I am interested only till $3$-dimensions)? How does varying the value of $\lambda$ determine the position of point $C$?

---

*[Click here](http://www.math.iitb.ac.in/~kdjoshi/jee2008.pdf) and see page 49, in case you want to access the original source of the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It comes from $$\overrightarrow{AC}=\lambda\overrightarrow{AB}$$